# How can I add values from an array to an object?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got an array :

```
let array = ["1#2","2#2","32#1","43#3","44#4","1#1","54#2","1#1"];
```

I've got a RegExp `(/(\d+)#(\d+)/g)` and could `.exec()` to the one of the group; On this RegExp I've got two groups of digits.

If **("key"/ first group)** equal we sum value of this **("key" first group)**.

How can I get this answer:

```
let answer = [
    { key: 1, value: 4 },     <==sum value of equal keys
    { key: 2, value: 2 },
    { key: 32, value: 1 },
    { key: 43, value: 3 },
    { key: 44, value: 4 },
    { key: 54, value: 2 } 
];
```

I'm trying to do this like :

```
let itemObject = {
    key: '',
    value: ''
}

array.map((item) => {
        let itemNumber = RegExp.exec(item);
        itemObject.key = itemNumber[1];
        itemObject.value = itemNumber[2];
        this.emptyArray.push(itemObject);
      })
```

But this not working ... and I don't know what to do.

Comment: No, but I see this post and want do something for me. But I'am new in this parts. So need a help.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and what you are having issues with? (Also, please refer to our [ask] page)

Comment: Sorry I'm a noob ))) read this page.  And now edit and questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use regex here, you can use `split` method to get keys and values. Additionally you can use `reduce` to get the result:

```js
    let array = ["1#2","2#2","32#1","43#3","44#4","1#1","54#2","1#1"];
    let answer = array.reduce((arr, curr)=> {
        let [key, value] = curr.split('#');
        let existing = arr.find(x => x.key === +key);
        if(existing){
            existing.value += +value;
        } else {
            arr.push({key:+key, value: +value});
        }
        return arr;
    }, []);
    
 console.log(answer);
```

Comment: I'm edit my questions I need if equal keys not duplicate it.

Comment: @DevFromEarth modified my answer, I guess you expect value 4 under key 1

Answer (score 2):

You could take a map and check if the key and value is equal. Then add the actual value.

```js
var array = ["1#2","2#2","32#1","43#3","44#4","1#1","54#2","1#1"],
    result = Array.from(
        array
            .reduce(
                (m, s) => (([k, v]) => m.set(k, (m.get(k) || 0) + v))(s.split('#').map(Number)),
                new Map
            )
            .entries(),
        ([key, value]) => ({ key, value })
    );
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Edit my question.

Comment: But I don't understand why you use new Map here?

Comment: map is for grouping the same key.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you iterate over array, split on # and take the first value as key and second as its corresponding value and put them in a hash map. (if you are sure # is used as splitter always).

Comment: Yeap split on # is good idea, but if I got RegExp that got two groups I not need to do split as I think, so I ask to help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is splitting by `#` and using the function `reduce` to group the objects.

```js
let array = ["1#2","2#2","32#1","43#3","44#4","1#1","54#2","1#1"];

let result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, c) => {
  let [key, value] = c.split('#'),
      accumKey = key + '|' + value,
      currentValue = key === value ? value : 0; 

  (a[accumKey] || (a[accumKey] = {key, value: 0})).value += Number(value);
  
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```